# How to create this layout with flexbox?

Tags: html, css, layout, flexbox

I have a list of divs like this:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
</div>
```

I'm trying to create the following layout, preferably with flexbox, but I have no idea how to.

[image: grid layout]

Comment: Use [CSS Grid](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/).

Comment: Wrap 2345 in their own container.

Answer (score 2):

You can use flexbox for this.

HTML

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="item">1</div>
    <div class="item">2</div>
    <div class="item">3</div>
    <div class="item">4</div>
    <div class="item">5</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.item {
  border: 2px solid #ddd;
  padding: 20px;
  background: grey;
  height: 50%;
  width: 25%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.item:nth-child(1) {
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

Demo: [**JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/prakashup/sjct8oz5/)

Comment: Nice! Way more elegant than my answer and no HTML edit. I like the way you think column-oriented

Comment: Thanks Stefan, Flex is very powerful, many complex grid and column design can be achieved. With newer browsers support it will be easy for developers to achieve complex design. A very good article on flexbox https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/  . A must read for frontend developers.

Answer (score 0):

As Yaakov Ainspan suggested, you should rather use [CSS Grid](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/) than flexbox for this task.

```css
    .container{
        display: grid;
        grid-template-columns: 50% auto auto;
        grid-template-rows: auto auto;
        height: 200px;
    }
    
    .container div {
      border: 2px solid #eee;
    }
    
    .item1 {
        grid-row-start: 1;
        grid-row-end: 3;
    }
```

```html
    <div class="container">
        <div class="item1">1</div>
        <div class="item">2</div>
        <div class="item">3</div>
        <div class="item">4</div>
        <div class="item">5</div>
    </div>
```

Comment: May I suggest including a jsFiddle and match the square height?

Answer (score 0):

So much flex, so little time. This is why people suggest CSS grid. Of course with this way I had to change the HTML structure

```css
body {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
}

.left {
  flex: 1 1 50%;
  display: flex;
}

.left .item {
  flex: 1;
}

.right {
  flex: 1 1 50%;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.right .item {
  flex: 0 1 48%;
}

.item {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  outline: 1px solid black;
  margin: 1%;
}

.item:before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  padding-top: 100%;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <section class="left">
    <div class="item">1</div>
  </section>
  <section class="right">
    <div class="item">2</div>
    <div class="item">3</div>
    <div class="item">4</div>
    <div class="item">5</div>
  </section>
</div>
```